# output the data to text file from select query in wqell formatted way

Tags: sql-server-2005

i have an table  customer

```
 CustomerID             DOB
 1                      11/12/1983
 2                      12/12/1983
 3                      12/12/1985
34334                   23/12/1986
 1232                   15/12/1983
 232                    13/12/1987
 343                    24/12/1987
 1342                   22/12/1988
 121111                 02/12/1989
 243233233              12/12/1983
```

When i output the data to an text  file the data is not getting well formatted,
 i neeed get the  result in a well  formatted  way like the below how can i set the result to get in this way

my out put should look like this

```
 CustomerID                     DOB
 000000001                      11/12/1983
 000000002                      12/12/1983
 000000003                      12/12/1985
 000034334                      23/12/1986
 000001232                      15/12/1983
 000000232                      13/12/1987
 000000343                      24/12/1987
 000001342                      22/12/1988
 000121111                      02/12/1989
 243233233                      12/12/1983
```

my query looks like this
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell'bcp "SELECT  * from MainDB.dbo.Customer" queryout "F:\output\Temp.txt" -c -T -x -t"|"'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `REPLICATE`.This will add the zeros at the start of the `CustomerID`. Like this:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(CustomerID INT)

INSERT INTO @tbl
VALUES
    (1),(2),(34334)

SELECT
   REPLICATE('0',9-LEN(CustomerID))+CAST(CustomerID AS VARCHAR(100))
FROM
   @tbl AS tbl
```

Reference [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174383.aspx)

**EDIT**

So your query will look something like this:

```
SELECT 
    (
       REPLICATE('0',9-LEN(CustomerID))+
       CAST(CustomerID AS VARCHAR(100))
    ) AS CustomerID,
    DOB
FROM 
    MainDB.dbo.Customer
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `CustomerID` column to a `varchar` (during the output process), and it should remove the leading zeros.